# How to insert into a table based on a multi-row subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, dml

I have a `Dashboard_Diagram` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Dashboard_Diagram
(
    diagram_id TINYINT,
    name VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO Dashboard_Diagram
    SELECT 1, 'Radar'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Bar'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'Pie'
```

I have `Dashboard_Configuration` table:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable
(
    user_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    diagram_id TINYINT
)
```

And `@user_id`:

```
DECLARE @user_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'E4F77F2C-8AA1-493A-94A3-03EA212453D4'
```

I want to dynamically insert rows into `Dashboard_Configuration`, based on the rows in `Dashboard_Diagram`. So statically this would look like:

```
INSERT INTO Dashboard_Configuration
@userId, 1
. . .
```

I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO Dashboard_Configuration
@user_id, (SELECT diagram_id FROM Dashboard_Diagram)
```

But this throws an error because the subquery returns more than one value:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

How can I insert into a table, based on a dynamic amount of rows from another table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO Dashboard_Configuration (User_id, name)
    SELECT @user_id, name
    FROM Dashboard_Diagram;
```

Note that this also lists the columns explicitly.  The names may not be correct (you don't specify them in the question), but it is a best practice to list the columns.

EDIT:

There is a type conflict above.  Do you really intend this?

```
INSERT INTO Dashboard_Configuration (User_id, diagram_id)
    SELECT @user_id, dd.diagram_id
    FROM Dashboard_Diagram dd;
```

Comment: If we are always inserting all the columns, why is implicitly bad practice?

Comment: @AugustWilliams . . . Things break when you add, move, or change the type of columns.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense.